# Move percentages out of pie chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this code

```
data <- read.csv("/home/miguel/Documentos/CSV_oficiales/docs_cnh.csv")
freq <- count(data, Documento.Vigente)

# Calcular los porcentajes
freq <- freq %>% mutate(Percentage = n / sum(n) * 100)

# Crear el gráfico de pastel utilizando ggplot2
ggplot(freq, aes(x = "", y = n, fill = Documento.Vigente)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  labs(fill = "Referencia") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues") +
  ggtitle("Documentos vigentes ante la CNH") +
  theme_void() +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(Percentage, 1), "%")), 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), 
            color = "white", size = 4)
```

I would like the percentages to be outside the chart foot, I tried this code but it didn't work.

```
+ theme(plot.margin = margin(1, 1, 1, 1, "cm"))
```

But didn't work
[image]

Comment: The best way to handle this is not to use a pie chart.  https://scc.ms.unimelb.edu.au/resources/data-visualisation-and-exploration/no_pie-charts

Comment: Have you tried `geom_label_repel` like in this example?  https://r-charts.com/part-whole/pie-chart-labels-outside-ggplot2/